# PostgreSQL csvlog: Large Message/Detail Truncated Causing Malformed CSV

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

In attempt to utilize a *foreign table* for PostgreSQL's log analysis, I set `log_destination=csvlog`. Because our application uses large JSON/XML data, which get logged in the messages, from day 1 we have been getting errors like the following, because the large contents in the `message` or `detail` field get truncated due to certain system limit.

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY postgresql_log_1, line 268367: "2017-05-17 09:46:37.419 PDT,"user","dbname",75303,"10.181.55.93:50206",591549a8.12627,11820,"I..."
```

*pgBadger* similarly errors out with large contents like the following, which I have submitted an issue at https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger/issues/342.

```
FATAL: cannot use CSV on /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-proddb.csv.1, EIQ - QUO character not allowed at line 766714
DETAIL: 2017-04-19 12:45:05.389 PDT,"user","dbname",56389,"10.181.55.94:50466",58f6f766.dc45,3870,"INSERT",2017-04-18 22:36:38 PDT,71/104232,3111351054,LOG,00000,"duration: 82.541 ms  execute <unnamed>: insert into EVENT_NOTIFICATION (ACTOR_ID, CREATED, DATA, TYPE, UPDATED, ID) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)","parameters: $1 = NULL, $2 = '2017-04-19 12:45:05.245-07', $3 = '{""productID"":""093707231228"",""fileData"":{""name"":""EPSON010.JPG"",""mimeType"":""image/jpeg"",""content"":""/9j/4QEGRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAIAA4BAgAQAA...
...AUUAF2017-04-19 12:45:11.174 PDT,"user","dbname",56389,"10.181.55.94:50466",58f6f766.dc45,3871,"SELECT",2017-04-18 22:36:38 PDT,71/104241,0,LOG,00000,"duration: 125.202 ms  execute <unnamed>: select max(cast(version as integer)) from category where org = $1","parameters: $1 = 'ST'",,,,,,,,""

reset CSV parser
```

I ended up with a workaround using the following *Python* script to repair the bad CSV contents.  I can now use a foreign table to analyze my `csvlog` via SQL queries, by getting rid of a few bad CSV records from the log.

I figure this must have been a common issue with a lot of Postgres folks out there and hope to find a more elegant approach to this issue.  Kindly share your solution on this post, if you have one.

Here is mine for now.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import os
import sys
import linecache as lc
import pyparsing as pp
from datetime import datetime

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)  # Max out the limit for large CSV contents
filename = sys.argv[1]
headers = [ 'log_time', 'user_name', 'database_name', 'process_id', 'connection_from',
            'session_id', 'session_line_num', 'command_tag', 'session_start_time',
            'virtual_transaction_id', 'transaction_id', 'error_severity', 'sql_state_code',
            'message', 'detail', 'hint', 'internal_query', 'internal_query_pos', 'context',
            'query', 'query_pos', 'location', 'application_name' ]

'''
Identify ranges of lines containing invalid CSV data
'''

bad_ranges = []
l_start = 0
with open(filename) as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=headers)
  for csv_dict in reader:
    # Extraneous columns beyond the predefined headers, keyed as None, indicate a bad csvlog.
    if None in csv_dict:
      bad_ranges += [(csv_dict, l_start, reader.line_num + 1,)]
    else:
      try: # Validate datetime format on log_time.
        datetime.strptime(csv_dict['log_time'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z')
      except ValueError:
        bad_ranges += [(csv_dict, l_start, reader.line_num + 1,)]
    l_start = reader.line_num + 1
  line_count = reader.line_num + 1

yyyy = pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=4).setName("yyyy")
mm   = pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=2).setName("mm")
dd   = pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=2).setName("dd")
HH24 = pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=2).setName("HH24")
MI   = pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=2).setName("MI")
SS   = pp.Word(pp.nums, exact=2).setName("SS")
TZ   = pp.Word(pp.alphas.upper(), exact=3).setName("TZ")
date = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd
time = HH24 + ":" + MI + ":" + SS + pp.Optional("." + pp.Word(pp.nums, max=3)) + " " + TZ
timestamptz = pp.Combine(date + " " + time)
mlDblQuoteString = pp.QuotedString('"', escQuote='""', multiline=True)
slDblQuoteString = pp.QuotedString('"', escQuote='""', multiline=False)
comma = pp.Suppress(',')

validCSVLog = timestamptz("log_time")                   + comma \
    + slDblQuoteString('user_name')                     + comma \
    + slDblQuoteString('database_name')                 + comma \
    + pp.Word(pp.nums)('process_id')                    + comma \
    + slDblQuoteString('connection_from')               + comma \
    + pp.Word(pp.hexnums + ".")('session_id')           + comma \
    + pp.Word(pp.nums)('session_line_num')              + comma \
    + slDblQuoteString('command_tag')                   + comma \
    + timestamptz('session_start_time')                 + comma \
    + pp.Combine(pp.Word(pp.nums) + pp.Literal("/")
        + pp.Word(pp.nums))('virtual_transaction_id')   + comma \
    + pp.Word(pp.nums)('transaction_id')                + comma \
    + pp.Word(pp.alphas.upper())('error_severity')      + comma \
    + pp.Word(pp.alphanums)('sql_state_code')           + comma \
    + pp.Optional(mlDblQuoteString)('message')          + comma \
    + pp.Optional(mlDblQuoteString)('detail')           + comma \
    + pp.Optional(mlDblQuoteString)('hint')             + comma \
    + pp.Optional(mlDblQuoteString)('internal_query')   + comma \
    + pp.Optional(pp.nums)('internal_query_pos')        + comma \
    + pp.Optional(mlDblQuoteString)('context')          + comma \
    + pp.Optional(mlDblQuoteString)('query')            + comma \
    + pp.Optional(pp.nums)('query_pos')                 + comma \
    + pp.Optional(slDblQuoteString)('location')         + comma \
    + pp.Optional(slDblQuoteString)('application_name') + pp.LineEnd().suppress()

'''
1. Scan for any valid CSV data to salvage from the malformed contents.
2. Make a new copy without the malformed CSV rows.
'''

if bad_ranges:
  l_lower = 0
  with open(filename+'.new', 'w') as t:
    for bad_dict, l_start, l_end in bad_ranges:
      t.writelines([lc.getline(filename, l) for l in range(l_lower,l_start)])
      bad_csv = ''.join([lc.getline(filename, l) for l in range(l_start,l_end)])
      print("{0:>8}: line[{1}:{2}] log_time={log_time} malformed CSV row found".format(
            'NOTICE', l_start, l_end-1, **bad_dict))
      for valid_dict, c_start, c_end in validCSVLog.scanString(bad_csv):
        print("{0:>8}: line[{1}:{2}] log_time={log_time} as valid CSV portion retained".format(
              'INFO', l_start, l_end-1, **valid_dict))
        good_csv = bad_csv[c_start:c_end]
        t.write(good_csv)
      l_lower = l_end
    t.writelines([lc.getline(filename, l) for l in range(l_lower, line_count)])

  # Back up old file as .bak
  backup = filename+'.bak'
  os.rename(filename, backup)
  print("{0:>8}: original file renamed to {1}".format('NOTICE', backup))
  os.rename(filename+'.new', filename)
```